# Build menu like this in drupal 7

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I have always been working on drop down menus which nice menus or sucker fish menus was satisfying. I have a new kind of menus to be satisfied.  As show in the image. When destination is hovered its should bring out drop down in that manner.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Megamenu module](http://drupal.org/project/megamenu) looks very promising (especially with JohnAlbin on board) but unfortunately there is no stable D7 version yet. You could try the development version though.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Superfish module (http://drupal.org/project/superfish), recently this has added an option for megamenu which will allow you to build a display much like your screenshot. You will need to tweak the css to get the display how you would like it.

Demo: http://mehrpadin.net/demo/superfish/ (hover over "products" in the very bottom menu)